# two magento site in one elasticsearch

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

Is it possible to run one elastic search on two different Magento 2 sites?

Currently, one Magento site running elastic search smoothly, but now I need to add elastic search in another Magento site also.

Will it conflict with the results? if yes, then how to resolve?

What is the role of the prefix index name in elastic search?

please help me make elastic search work with two magento sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the exact role of the index prefix. You can have multiple applications write and read to / from the same ES instance. You can have 2 magento websites using the same ES. Just make sure you set different prefixes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will try to do with that.

Answer (score 3):

Simply you have to change the Index Prefix for each Magento 2 website.

You can do this by going to **Stores** > **Configuration** > **CATALOG** > **Catalog Search**. then update the ***Elasticsearch Index Prefix*** as following:

[image]

This value '**magento2**' is the default values for all Magento 2, you can use your custom.

Thanks,